# hidden_html - What is this for?

Tags: webserver

My host provides pre-made folders (`softaculous`, `public_html`, `public_ftp`) and one of them is `hidden_html`.  I'm curious as to what this folder is for. I realize it's just a folder on the server and right now it's just housing the 2009 version of my site.

Can this folder be used for anything special, or is it just there for looks?

Comment: This may be a better question for your host's support forum.  Without seeing the hosting config, we're speculating.

Comment: If it was premade, with a name like that I would check the permissions. Maybe it is there but not accessible publicly.

Answer (score 1):

The browser generally access content from the `public_html` folder. The `hidden_html` folder is for housing content not accessible from the public browser. It's general purpose is for doing just what you are, housing archived versions of the site, because you can have the whole directory structure in there.

I'm not really sure of an special or *interesting* uses for it. I've never really put it to use like that. The most I've done is used it for archives and to put changes up there before moving them over to public.